# Excel VBA code stop working when the Source file Data Changed

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using the following code successfully for a few days, but it started encountering issues when the data changed in the `Source File`. Now, the code makes the file `Not Responding.` The `Source File` used to contain around 500K rows, and it was working fine. However, it's now struggling even with 350K rows.

The code's purpose is to extract data from a different workbook, copying entire rows based on matching values, and pasting them into `Destination File` Sheet2.

I suspect the slowdown is due to the time it takes to search, resulting in the `Not Responding` issue.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks."

I've included a link that contains both files, which should provide a clearer understanding of the issue. [Files](https://files.fm/u/qgzyfpa9s)

```
Sub FMID()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wsHF As Worksheet
    Dim wsWellcare As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim source1Data As Variant
    Dim source2Data As Variant
    Dim targetRow As Long
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Source File.xlsx")
    Set wsHF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsWellcare = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    lastRow2 = wsWellcare.Cells(wsWellcare.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow2 > 1 Then
        wsWellcare.Range("A2:A" & lastRow2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    lastRow = wsHF.Cells(wsHF.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    source1Data = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value

    Dim searchDictionary As Object
    Set searchDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Populate the dictionary with source data
    PopulateDictionary source1Data, searchDictionary
    
    For targetRow = 2 To lastRow
        searchValue = wsHF.Cells(targetRow, "C").Value
        
        If searchValue <> "" And searchDictionary.Exists(searchValue) Then
            Dim rowNumbers As Collection
            Set rowNumbers = searchDictionary(searchValue)
            
            Dim i As Variant
            For Each i In rowNumbers
                Dim sourceRow As Long
                sourceRow = i ' The row number in the source data
                Dim targetRowWellcare As Long
                targetRowWellcare = wsWellcare.Cells(wsWellcare.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                
                ' Copy the data from source1Data to wsWellcare
                Dim sourceDataColumns As Long
                sourceDataColumns = UBound(source1Data, 2)
                
                Dim columnOffset As Long
                columnOffset = 0 ' Adjust this based on the target column you want to copy to
                
                wsWellcare.Cells(targetRowWellcare, "A").Resize(1, sourceDataColumns).Value = _
                    Application.Index(source1Data, sourceRow, 0)
                
            Next i
        End If
    Next targetRow
    MsgBox "DATA HAS BEEN COPIED SUCCESSFULLY"
    wsWellcare.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub PopulateDictionary(sourceData As Variant, ByRef dictionary As Object)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)
        Dim searchValue As Variant
        searchValue = sourceData(i, 3)
        If Not IsEmpty(searchValue) Then
            If Not dictionary.Exists(searchValue) Then
                Set dictionary(searchValue) = New Collection
            End If
            dictionary(searchValue).Add i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: After `Set wb1 = Workbooks("Source File.xlsx")` add `MsgBox wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address` to check you don't have more lines than you think.

Comment: Yeah you're right there are 367K+ rows

Comment: Put some timing code into your Sub and you can get some idea exactly how long each part takes.

Comment: Yeah i will do it once i will be back in office.

Comment: Aside: Why not use a database (MS Access if on Windows, SQLite if on Mac)? You could avoid looped searches. Let's not overuse Excel!

Comment: Check the value of `lastRow` after you have set it with `lastRow = wsHF.Cells(wsHF.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: As your other questions indicate that you _do_ have MS365, you can actually do this with a formula: (assuming you have _Source File.xlsx_ open) `=FILTER('[Source File.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$H$367997,ISNUMBER(MATCH('[Source File.xlsx]Sheet1'!C2:C367997,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,0)))`

Comment: @TimWilliams i have added a time and the code stucks on search loop using decitionary.

Comment: Adding all the data to MS Access and then will try to pull it using Excel VBA @Parfait

Comment: Thank you for your Solution! I have 365 but some of my team member do not have. @Spectral Instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might seem convenient to use `Application.Index` to "slice" an array to get a single row, but the truth is that it's **really slow**, so you should avoid it at all costs if you want your code to run as quickly as possible.  It's better to write a small function in VBA to pick out the row.

Here's an illustration of just how slow it can be, particularly if your source array is large:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Const NUM_ROWS As Long = 200000
    Dim source1Data, i As Long, t As Double, n As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J11").Resize(NUM_ROWS)
        .Value = "blah"
        source1Data = .Value
    End With
    
    Debug.Print "# of source rows:", NUM_ROWS
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 20
        n = 1 + CLng(Rnd() * (NUM_ROWS - 2))
        ActiveSheet.Range("L1").Resize(1, 10).Value = Application.Index(source1Data, n, 0)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Index", Timer - t
    
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 20
        n = 1 + CLng(Rnd() * (NUM_ROWS - 2))
        ActiveSheet.Range("L1").Resize(1, 10).Value = SliceRow(source1Data, n)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "SliceRow", Timer - t
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Function SliceRow(arr, rownum As Long)
    Dim rw(), c As Long
    ReDim rw(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    For c = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        rw(1, c) = arr(rownum, c)
    Next c
    SliceRow = rw
End Function
```

Notice we're only picking out **20 rows** - here's the output:

```
# of source rows:  350000 
Index              12.775390625   '<<< yikes!
SliceRow           0.001953125    '<<< much better...
```

I believe the slowness with `Index` is because worksheet functions are optimized to work with data on a worksheet, not in a VBA array, so the array first needs to be re-worked into a format that `Index` can deal with, and you're doing that with a 350k-row array every time you make a call to `Index`.  The VBA alternative just references the array as-is, and so can much faster. The performance difference between the two approaches gets larger as the array size increases.

---

Back to the actual use case...
In testing, this was pretty fast for me (<2sec): added some batching up of matched rows to limit the number of writes to the sheet.

```vb
Sub FMID()
    Const COLLECT_SIZE As Long = 20000  'batch up this many rows when searching
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wsHF As Worksheet, wsWellcare As Worksheet
    Dim source1Data As Variant, numCols As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim cDest As Range, c As Long
    Dim searchDictionary As Object, outRow As Long, arrOut(), r As Long, tmp
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Source File.xlsx")
    Set wsHF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsWellcare = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'clear any previous data
    lastRow = wsWellcare.Cells(wsWellcare.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > 1 Then wsWellcare.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Set cDest = wsWellcare.Range("A2") 'results start here
    
    'get all unique search terms as dictionary keys
    Set searchDictionary = UniquesFromRange(wsHF.Range("C2:C" & _
                           wsHF.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row))
    
    'pick up all source data
    source1Data = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
    numCols = UBound(source1Data, 2)              'how many source columns
    ReDim arrOut(1 To COLLECT_SIZE, 1 To numCols) 'size output array
    outRow = 0
    
    'Loop and check source data against search terms
    '   Batch up matched rows and place on worksheet once/if limit is reached
    For r = 2 To UBound(source1Data)
        tmp = CStr(source1Data(r, 3)) 'cast to String to match dictionary keys
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
            If searchDictionary.Exists(tmp) Then 'want this row?
                outRow = outRow + 1
                For c = 1 To numCols 'copy over this row to `arrOut`
                    arrOut(outRow, c) = source1Data(r, c)
                Next c
            End If
            If outRow = COLLECT_SIZE Then                      'output array is full?
                cDest.Resize(outRow, numCols).Value = arrOut   'place the values
                ReDim arrOut(1 To COLLECT_SIZE, 1 To numCols)  'clear output array
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(outRow)               'next destination cell
                outRow = 0                                     'reset row
                Debug.Print "pasted"
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    'any last rows to place?
    If outRow > 0 Then cDest.Resize(outRow, numCols).Value = arrOut
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    MsgBox "DATA HAS BEEN COPIED SUCCESSFULLY"
    wsWellcare.Activate
End Sub

'Return a scripting dictionary with all unique non-blank values from `rng`
Function UniquesFromRange(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim c As Range, tmp, d As Object
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'd.comparemode=1 'case-insensitive
    For Each c In rng.Cells
       tmp = Trim(c.Value)
       If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
            If Not d.Exists(tmp) Then d.Add tmp, 1
       End If
    Next c
    Set UniquesFromRange = d
End Function
```

Comment: Since items are added to the Dictionary as Strings (via the `TRIM()` function), but the 3rd column of the source data contains integers, I think the following cast is required `tmp = Cstr(source1Data(r, 3))` inside the loop?

Comment: @SpectralInstance - thanks I missed that...

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams this is brillaint approach.

Answer (score 3):

Consider running SQL if using Excel for PC since Excel can connect to the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files) to run queries on worksheets as if they were database tables. You can query the very workbook you run the macro using its last saved instance and can query from an external workbook.

Specifically, the query below runs an `INNER JOIN` between the target and source sheets and outputs results to existing worksheet, *wsWellcare*. Note: Please adjust workbook paths and column names in connection and SQL strings.

```vb
Sub RunSQL()    
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    ' CONNECTION AND SQL STRINGS
    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Current\Workbook.xlsm;"
    
    strSQL = "SELECT src.*" _
                & " FROM [Sheet1$] wsHF" _
                & " INNER JOIN [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Source.xlsx].[Sheet1$] src" _
                & "    ON wsHF.ColumnName = src.ColumName;" 
           
    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn
    
    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wsWellcare")
        For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Next i        
        ' DATA ROWS
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    End With
        
    rst.Close: conn.Close 
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing   
End Sub
```

---

Ideally, however, for the long term consider a database solution with Excel serving only for end use reporting or graphing needs and not to house or process such large data. If on PC, you can use MS Access, the database sibling to Excel, which you can run similar workbook queries to create tables and query via the Access SQL query design window. From there, use query wherever databases can be accessed including Excel with the Access ODBC driver.

Make-Table Queries

```sql
SELECT *
INTO wsh
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Target_File.xlsx].[Sheet1$]
```

```sql
SELECT *
INTO src
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Source_File.xlsx].[Sheet1$]
```

Recordset Query

```sql
SELECT src.*
FROM wsHF
INNER JOIN src
   ON wsHF.ColumnName = src.ColumName;
```

---

If using Excel for Mac, consider exporting your Excel workbook data into CSV files. Then, import the two CSVs into the open source SQLite database using its [command line shell](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats). From there, create a view for your target data and use it wherever databases can be accessed including Excel with the SQLite ODBC driver.

```sql
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS wsWellcare AS 
SELECT source_file.*
FROM wsHF
INNER JOIN source_file
   ON wsHF.ColumnName = src.ColumName;
```